# Working with multiple activity and keeping the same value of intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have three activity 'a', 'b' and 'c' as shown below.
activity 'a' send a value (i.e. 1) when the button (button_a) is clicked to activity 'b'.
activity 'b' gets the value and display it, later when button (pause) is clicked, activity 'c' is shown.
In activity 'c', when we click the play button, the value (i.e. 1) is not displayed.

So how to display the value back to activity 'b' after the play button is clicked?

activity 'a':

```
    Button button_a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);
    button_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(aActivity.this, bActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("value", "1");   
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        }); 

    Button button_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_b);
    button_b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(aActivity.this, bActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("value", "2");   
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

activity 'b':

```
    TextView levelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String level = i.getStringExtra("value");
    levelName.setText(level);


    Button pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(b.this, c.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

activity 'c':

```
    Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(c.this, b.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: you want pass the data to all activates.

Comment: absolutely and the data must be based on the activity 'a' buttons. If the button clicked is 'a' then the value passed should be 1. Updated my question too :)

Comment: use bundle to pass the data to all activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the "b" activity again from the "c" activity which is creating the new instance of Activity so at this point the activity stack looks like this

a -> b(which has value) -> c -> b (new instance of b with no value)

So rather than trying to load the "b" activity again, just finish the Activity "c" so the Activity stack becomes

a -> b (which has value)

Example

```
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
});
```

Added: Please refer **[Task and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)**